# Can TFS build-server compare tests performance after each build?

Tags: testing, tfs

I want to observe the dynamics of performance changes.

For example, I have method which generates random number. The first version of this method spends 350 ms to generate. The second version spends 450 ms.

Tests on the TFS build server have to throw error because now the method is running slower.

Can TFS storage and compare previous performance results?
How to write test methods to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that instead of doing something as complicated as comparing does why not just f run it once and decide.

You can easily compare the current execution time to a 350ms baseline and fail the test of it goes over.

If you go down the road of comparing to the last you will unnecessarily increase the test time. You will add the time to load the last from storage and danger the new value...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to measure the time needed to perform the calculations. After the calculations are done you write the time needed in to a file. On the next testrun you compare the measured time to the value in the file. If It's the same or faster you replace the value in the file and let the test succeed.

If it is higher, you fail the test and write the time previously needed and the time your test needed this time as your fail message.

If the file does not exist, your test has to succeed since it can't compare the measured time.

Of course that's not using the TFS test environment directly, but this way you can fine tune your stuff the exact way you want it.